# Custom property setter in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an `iframe` and it's contents should be bound to a controller function. I tried

```
<iframe ng-bind-html-unsafe="selectedMessage.content()"></iframe>
```

but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work. The correct way to write contents to an `iframe` would be to gain access to the `iframe` DOM element and invoke `ifrmElem.contentDocument.write(s)`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting a watcher on a property, and then manually updating the iframe when required.

Example below uses cross-browser iframe content selection.

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uyLNY/2/

```
$scope.$watch('data.content', function(oldValue, newValue) {
    var ifrm = $element.find('iframe')[0];
    ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;       
    ifrm.document.open();
    ifrm.document.write(newValue);
    ifrm.document.close();

});
```

However worth noting I am unsure of the performance of this, if you were to be writing a large amount of content.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/LG7p1AG7yhVKyLXgMX4Q?p=preview

Javascript

```
  $scope.content= "";

  $scope.fillFrame = function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).contentDocument.write($scope.content);  
  };
```

HTML

```
 <strong>Enter some html</strong>
    <br/>
    <textarea ng-model="content"></textarea>
    <button ng-click="fillFrame('frame')">Fill iFrame</button>
```